# Session variables are not being set, php sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

So my problem is that i'm trying to check if some session variables are set, and they should be, but when I check them they dont have a value.

So first of I have this HTML form that takes an Email and Password input
HTML CODE:

```
<form class="login_form" action="includes/process_login.php" method="POST" name="login_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" >
    <input type="button" value="LOGIN" class="login_button" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">
</form>
```

And as you can see my submit button first of all goes to a javascript that hashes the input.
JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";
    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit(); 
}
```

And after it is done hashing the password it sends the form information to the target which is "includes/process_login.php"

PROCESS_LOGIN.PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1['.$email.', '.$password.']');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

And from here it sends the $email and $password values into the function login:

FUNCTION LOGIN CODE:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli){
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
            if(checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true){
                return false;
            }else{
                if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $db_password . $user_browser);

                    return true;
                }else{
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here comes part of the problem, in this code it stores a session:user_id values, session:username value and session:login_string value.
But the problem is that the session does not get stored anything.

Because when I then get redirected to the so called "protected_page.php" it then checks if these values are set or not and returns that they are not set.

THE LOGIN_CHECK CODE ( that checks if we are logged in or not)

```
function login_check($mysqli){
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'],
              $_SESSION['username'], 
              $_SESSION['login_string']
             )) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        echo $user_id;

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                  FROM users 
                                  WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result();
             if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if (hash_equals($login_check, $login_string) ){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
             }else{
                 return false; 
             }
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }else{
        return false; 
    }

}
```

Sorry about this post being very long, but I could really need some new angles. Thanks!

PS Here is the "custom set session function"

```
function sec_session_start(){
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';
    session_name($session_name);

    $secure = true;
    $httponly = true;

    if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE){
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
                             $cookieParams["path"],
                             $cookieParams["domain"],
                             $secure,
                             $httponly);

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

Comment: Is your session started via session_start()?

Comment: Yea it should. My bad though, did not add the custom set session function, but it is in there now :)

Comment: Have you checked if your session variables are not created because the password verification fails?

Comment: try putting this at the beginning of your function login_check `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see the data(s) save in your session

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak hash like SHA512**.

Comment: @Shadow Yes since it returns true and send me to the protected page, it should be creating those.

Comment: @Beginner Yes tried that too, it returns array(0) so obviously it doesn't set the session variables :(

Comment: @Aplex in your login page did you successfully put `session_start();`?

Comment: @Beginner I'm pretty sure I did, I just 5 min ago ran out of options, so I changed the custom function sec_session_start() with just session_start, It now workes, it saves the variables and protected page does recognize the values, how ever I do want the custom function to work I just dont see what the problem is :)